# BottomNavigationView on databinding inside viewmodel

Tags: android, android-layout, mvvm, android-databinding, bottomnavigationview

layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
             app:onNavigationItemSelected="@{viewModel.onNavigationItemSelected}"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_home_tab" />
```

code:

```
@BindingAdapter("onNavigationItemSelected")
    public static void setOnNavigationItemSelected(
            BottomNavigationView view, BottomNavigationView listener) {
        view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                        Log.d("test","test1");
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                        Log.d("test","test2");
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
            }

        });

    }
```

This returns an error

```
Error:(183, 49) Could not find accessor viewmodel.onNavigationItemSelected
```

I am trying to implement databinding on my bottomnavigationview

Comment: Is `onNavigationItemSelected` declared as a field in your code? Or are you only using this getter method?

Comment: no it is not declared as field

Comment: Then you should try to do so, since Android is not able to find it.

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen Can you show some working code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have `onNavigationItemSelected()` declared in your `viewModel` class:

```
class ViewModel {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                Log.d("test","test1");
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                Log.d("test","test2");
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your xml, use method reference:

```
app:onNavigationItemSelected="@{viewModel::onNavigationItemSelected}"
```

Comment: do you have sample example for this?

Comment: Doesn't this break rules for keeping UI out of the view model?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it will be helpful to someone, detailed addition to accepted answer with setting selected item in xml.

**BindingAdapters**:

```
public class BindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter("onNavigationItemSelected")
    public static void setOnNavigationItemSelected(
            BottomNavigationView view, BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener listener) {
        view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(listener);
    }

    @BindingAdapter("selectedItemPosition")
    public static void setSelectedItemPosition(
            BottomNavigationView view, int position) {
        view.setSelectedItemId(position);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**:

```
public class ViewModel implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_favourites:
                Log.d("testTag","Selected favourites");
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_photos:
                Log.d("testTag","Selected photos");
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_info:
                Log.d("testTag","Selected info");
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Layout with **BottomNavigationView**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".views.MainActivity">

    <data>
        <import
            type="com.test.R"/>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.test.viewmodels.ViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            app:selectedItemPosition="@{R.id.navigation_photos}"
            app:onNavigationItemSelected="@{viewModel::onNavigationItemSelected}"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: this is not very useful because the ViewModel should have a variable with the selected menu item which reflects the selected item, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are struggling in Kotlin and having trouble creating Binding Adapter, do it like this:

```
 import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
 import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

 class BindingAdapters {
     companion object{
         @JvmStatic
         @BindingAdapter("onNavigationItemSelected")
         fun setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(view: BottomNavigationView, listener: BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener?) {
            view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(listener)
         }
     }
 }
```

And in your XML File, refer to the method you created in your ViewModel:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/orange"
            app:onNavigationItemSelected="@{viewModel::onBottomMenuClicked}"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
```

And in **ViewModel** Class:

```
fun onBottomMenuClicked(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home->{
                ...
                return true
            }
            R.id.navigation_search->{
                ...
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

non of the answers I saw were satisfying for me because I wanted the ViewModel to hold a variable which would reflect the selected menu item. this way I could not only programmatically change the selected item if needed through the viewmodel, but also get the id of the selected item. I tried a 2-way databinding with `InverseBindingAdapter` but sometimes ran into circular update loops. I finally ended up dong this solution which works fine.

```
@BindingAdapter("navItemSelectedHandler")
fun BottomNavigationView.setNavItemSelectedHandler(
        listener: BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
) = setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(listener)

@BindingAdapter("selectedMenuItemId")
fun BottomNavigationView.setSelectedMenuItemId(menuItemId: Int) {
    if (menuItemId != selectedItemId) {
        selectedItemId = menuItemId
    }
}
```

in the viewmodel:

```
val selectedMenuItemId = MutableLiveData(R.id.nav_menu_home)
val navItemSelectedHanlder = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    // ...
    if (selectedMenuItemId.value != item.itemId) {
        selectedMenuItemId.postValue(item.itemId)
    }
    true
}
```

and in the xml:

```
    app:selectedMenuItemId="@{viewModel.selectedMenuItemId}"
    app:navItemSelectedHandler="@{viewModel.navItemSelectedHanlder}"
```

I think there could be a better way using an `InverseBindingAdapter` but I also needed to add some other custom handlers in `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.